# Pygame - add text to class instance of a rect

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, pygame, rect

I am attempting to add text to class instances of a rect.

I have been able to do this by setting the "font" variable outside of the class and putting the desired text in "font.render_to" within the draw funtion but this means the text will be the same for all buttons as it is set within the class.

I'd like to set different text for each button specified in the class instance (button1, button2, button3) as shown in the below code but im getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path_to_file/test.py", line 30, in <module>
button1 = Button(10, 10, 100, 50, 'One')
File "path_to_file/test.py", line 23, in __init__
self.font = font.pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pygame'.
```

Code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import pygame.freetype


pygame.display.init()
pygame.freetype.init()
width = 300
height = 350
bg = (255, 255, 255)

# Sets the window size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# Sets the background colour to white
screen.fill(bg)


# Button class - All buttons are created using the below parameters
class Button:

    def __init__(self, rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height, font):
        self.rect_x = rect_x
        self.rect_y = rect_y
        self.rect_width = rect_width
        self.rect_height = rect_height
        self.font = font.pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)

# Draw function - Creates the rectangle and adds text
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 200), (self.rect_x, self.rect_y, self.rect_width, self.rect_height))
        self.font.render_to(screen, (42, 25), self.font, bg)


# Class instances - Defines button size and location in the PyGame window
button1 = Button(10, 10, 100, 50, 'One')
button2 = Button(10, 70, 100, 50, 'Two')
button3 = Button(10, 130, 100, 50, 'Three')

# game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    button1.draw()
    button2.draw()
    button3.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Maybe you should renamed the `font` parameter to `text`; then it should become clear what you're doing wrong (trying to use the attribute `font` for both the font object and the text value).

Comment: Take a close look at the last line of the constructor. You are doing `self.font = 'One'.pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)` and it is saying that str (in this case 'One') doesn't have a pygame attribute. As @sloth suggests, you should use the variable name `text` and `self.text` to store the string and `self.font` to store the font. You will have to change it in the `draw` function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th argument of the constructor is the text. You have to store the text in an attribute and render the text.
`font.pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)` doesn't make any sense. The font object is constructed by `pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)`.
The target position of `render_to` depends on the position of the button:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height, text):
        self.rect_x = rect_x
        self.rect_y = rect_y
        self.rect_width = rect_width
        self.rect_height = rect_height   
        self.text = text   
        self.font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 25)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 200, 200), 
            (self.rect_x, self.rect_y, self.rect_width, self.rect_height))     
        self.font.render_to(screen, (self.rect_x + 42, self.rect_y + 25), self.text, bg)
```